# How to update Xcode from 7.2.1 to 7.3.1 using terminal (commandline tools)

Tags: terminal, command-line, xcode, mac-appstore, software-update

I just need to know if there's a way to update Xcode from 7.2.1 to 7.3.1 using terminal (command line interface)?

The reason is I updated the Xcode via Mac App Store and once it was installed, the Xcode is still showing the version as Xcode 7.2.1.

I've been searching here as well as over Google and I couldn't find any info regarding this.

Comment: What does the update tan in App Store Application show?

Comment: Just make sure it is in this address: `/Applications/Xcode.app`, remove the app from your dock and open it at `/Applications/Xcode.app` then pin to dock. It might be a broken link maybe? `Cmnd+spacebar` and search for Xcode.app and see if there isn't more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the version of macOS/OS X that you have installed as well as your boot volume's storage, you might not see the version of Xcode.app in your /Applications folder update immediately after updating from the App Store app.

For a relatively easy way to deal with MAS apps and updates, check out the `mas` recipe in [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

https://github.com/mas-cli/mas

> A simple command line interface for the Mac App Store. Designed for scripting and automation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo softwareupdate --list

sudo softwareupdate --install NAME
```

But i would not recommend it.

Comment: why wouldn't you recommend it?

Answer (score -1):

You need upgrade the computer system!

Comment: could you expand on why?

Comment: And is there a way to do this with the command line? My App Store isn't working

Comment: sorry，there's no command line; How can your App Store isn't working,I never find this situation!  Last time,when I upgrade the Xcode,it tips that:you should upgrade the computer system! after i do it,it OK!

Answer (score -1):

Another best way to update and upgrade OSX development tools using command line is as follows:

Open terminal on OSX and type below commands. Try 'sudo' as prefix if you don't have admin privileges.

```
brew update
```

and for upgrading outdated tools and libraries use below command

```
brew upgrade
```

These will update all packages like node, rethinkDB and much more.

Also, `softwareupdate --install --all` this command also work best.

Comment: Note that this, of course, requires homebrew to be installed.

Comment: @JMY1000: Absolutely right!

Paste below code in terminal to install homebrew: 
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Source: https://brew.sh/